# bbwc battery replacement on MSA1000?

Tags: storage-area-network

Noob warning

Would someone tell me where it's located at so I can replace it?

This doc tells me it has one.
http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00147475.pdf
I took the lid off of one this morning to search for it and didn't see it.
The chassis is labeled as a 1500CS the controller in the chassis is labeled as a MSA1000. I've also read Array Config Utility User guide. Release date Jan2006 First Edition.

Comment: I'd guess this would be your best bet: http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01478890&sp4ts.oid=377751&lang=en-us&cc=us there's a video in there: http://www.hp.com/go/sml?media=EF73FC67-8EC3-4318-BA21-C57089A4A1F6/MSA1000_FRU_video_cache(arrayaccelerator).htm

Comment: I'm wanting to mark your answer as accepted but I don't see the "check mark" beside your answer to toggle it to green.  I'm going to guess that  it takes awhile for the check mark to show up.

Comment: No, it's a comment, not an answer. I'll write it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

[HP documentation](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01478890&sp4ts.oid=377751&lang=en-us&cc=us) has a [video](http://www.hp.com/go/sml?media=EF73FC67-8EC3-4318-BA21-C57089A4A1F6/MSA1000_FRU_video_cache(arrayaccelerator).htm) of the procedure.
It's usually bad form to leave a link as an answer with no further content, but in this case the video is probably the best answer.
Should HP remove the video, I doubt very much anyone else will carry it, so this answer will likely be worthless.

The HP doc title to help in possible future searches:

> HP StorageWorks 1000 Modular Smart Array - Removing and Replacing the
>   Cache (Array Accelerator)